# Handling an unknown number of objects in Java

Tags: java, object

A frequent problem I encounter when programming is how to handle an unknown number of objects. By handling I mean referencing them, manipulating them etc. As for me, this would be when developing smaller games and programs.

Currently I am working on a score-keeping program, which should display the names of the players, their score as well and various other features. Furthermore, there should be two buttons that allow for adding and removing players from the score table which is what I'll be focusing on here. It might look something like this:

```
//A very limited version of my program
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class Application extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    //Fields, variables and components
    Container mainCont = getContentPane();      //Main container, the window itself
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JPanel namePanel;
    private JButton addPlayerButton;
    private JButton removePlayerButton;
    //...
    //Many more components

    public Application(){

        //Basic window initiation
        setTitle("Score Keeper");
        this.setSize(650, 700);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainCont.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setContentPane(mainCont);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        namePanel = new JPanel();

        addPlayerButton = new JButton();
        addPlayerButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(addPlayerButton);

        removePlayerButton = new JButton();
        removePlayerButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(removePlayerButton);

        this.add(buttonPanel);
        this.add(namePanel);
        this.setVisible(true);

        //Other code omitted for now
        //Includes other graphic components, layout managers etc.

    }

    /*
    * Action-Listener. 
    * Performs an event on an action.
    */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        if(event.getSource() == addPlayerButton){
            Application.Player newPlayer = this.new Player();    //Creates a new object, i.e. a new player
            //See below for Player class
        }

        if(event.getSource() == removePlayerButton){
            //******
            // This is where the problem lies
        }

    }

    //I use a nested class to create a new player
    public class Player{

        //Components etc.

        private String name;
        private JLabel nameLabel;

        public Player(){

            name = getName();
            nameLabel = new JLabel(name);
            namePanel.add(nameLabel);


        }

        public String getName(){
            //This basically gets input from the user to assign a name to the new player
            //Code omitted for now

        }

    }

}
```

So far all is good. This program basically only has two buttons, where the addPlayerButton adds a player object, which has a name that is displayed on the screen. Every time this button is pressed a new player is added to the screen. And this can be done an indefinite number of times.

The problem comes when we want to remove a player. How can we do that? We can't reference it by name, as all player objects are practically anonymous.

The alternative, of course, would be to pre-define a fixed amount of player objects:

```
class Application extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    //Fields, variables and components
    Container mainCont = getContentPane();      //Main container, the window itself
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JPanel namePanel;
    private JButton addPlayerButton;
    private JButton removePlayerButton;

    private Player player1;
    private Player player2;
    private Player player3;
    //...
    //Etc.
```

Then we would be able to directly address each player object, but this is simply too impractical. We cannot add more players than the pre-defined amount, and if we want fewer players we have a bunch of player objects that are never used. Furthermore, we would have to hardcode every initiation of every player - every nameLabel would have to be manually added to the screen etc.

Please share your knowledge on how you handle this kind of problem, of how you deal with an unknown number of objects.
Thanks for taking the time and for the help!

*P.S. I'm still pretty new to this forum. Please let me know if there is anything with this question I can change etc. I did my research and found no previous question that tackled this, but if there is one I missed feel free to let me know!*

EDIT 1: Okay. There were a lot of great answers. I chose the one using hashmaps as the right solution, since I consider this the best solution for the premises I provided. The way I actually solved my problem is that I added, to the player object, a JButton that removes the player object it is stored in. I also scrapped the concept of using a nested class for the player and just implemented it in a separate class. 
What I've learnt overall, though, is that when handling objects and you don't know the amount of objects it is generally best to store them in a collection of some sort. My preference is the Hashmap, as it provides an easy way of accessing the object based on one of its properties, like a String name or similar.

Comment: You should look into [lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Those are exactly what you want.

Comment: @Ben I'm unsure exactly how I would be able to remove a player, even if the player object is stored in a list. Would you mind explaining a bit more in-depth on how I could implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Map/Hashmap and each time you create a player, add them to the map.

You also have to change from directly drawing the player on the screen, probably to drawing all the players in the Map, that way when a player gets removed from the Map it would no longer be drawn.

You would do something like this:

```
    Map<String, Player> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(player.Name, player);
```

And then you would draw everything in that hashmap. To remove you just need to provide the name of the player to remove.

```
    map.remove(player.Name);
```

And of course then you would change your code a bit to render everything inside the map, I believe you need a way to know which player is to be removed, you might want to add a text field to input the name of the player to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do if you want to delete a `Player` based on it's name is the following:

```
// Create a list of players, which you can define globally
ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

// The name of the player to find
String name = "theNameOfThePlayerToFind";

// Loop through the players and remove the player with the given name
for (Player player : players) {
    if (player.getName().equals(name)) {
        players.remove(player);
    }
}
```

You can also add new players to lists easily:

```
players.add(new Player());
```

Comment: This is a very neat solution. I didn't choose this answer, since I found @Katada's solution slightly more effective. They're pretty similar though, to be honest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would @Katada Freije method of using a HashMap. Just to elaborate a little, you basically have a collection of `Players` with their names as a key. You then use the key to remove the `Player`.

But I might also avoid this as some scenarios have multiple `Players` with the same name. I'd go with a `List<Player>`. This way the `Player` will be defined by the index rather than the name. You'd then use the index to remove the player with some in inbuilt [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that you are using a `JList` to display the current players. Java's Swing separates the *model* (where the objects that are displayed are actually stored) and the *view and control* (the `JList` that displays them). This design is called [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), and is very common.

We have different ways of storing the actual `Player` objects. Which to choose depends on how you plan to manipulate your players. The most straightforward is to use an array, but that only works if you will never have too many players:

```
 Player[] players = new Player[MAX_PLAYERS](); // define MAX_PLAYERS somewhere
 int currentPlayers = 0;                       // always < MAX_PLAYERS
```

To expose this to the `JList`, you would use a custom adapter model as follows (in an inner class with access to the players array):

```
 private final class PlayerListModel extends AbstractListModel<Player> {
     @Override
     Player getElementAt(int position) { return players[position]; }
     @Override
     int getSize() { return currentPlayers; }
 }
```

You can then pass this to the JList at construction time:

```
 private PlayerListModel playerListModel = new PlayerListModel();
 private JList playersListView = new JList(playerListModel);
```

Now, to remove a player by name, you would first update the model, and then cause the view to be refreshed:

```
 private void removePlayerByName(String name) {
     int toRemove = -1;
     for (int i=0; i<currentPlayers; i++) {
        Player p = players[i];
        if (p.getName().equals(name)) {
           toRemove = i;
           break;
        }
     }
     if (toRemove != -1) {
        // update model
        currentPlayers --; 
        players[toRemove] = players[currentPlayers];

        // update views
        playerListModel.fireContentsChanged(this, toRemove, currentPlayers);           
     }
 }
```

Instead of a `players` array, it would be much easier and safer to use an `ArrayList<Player> players`. However, if you are naming your variables `player1`, `player2` and so on, I think that you should begin with arrays. If you want to have much faster lookup of players, then a `TreeMap<String, Player>` would keep them sorted by name and easy to find. You would, in both cases, have to update the model and the `removePlayerByName` function accordingly. For example, if using the `TreeMap`, it would be much shorter (and faster):

```
 private void removePlayerByName(String name) {
    if (players.containsKey(name)) {
      players.remove(name);
      playerListModel.fireContentsChanged(this, 0, currentPlayers);           
    }
 }
```

On the other hand, it is far more common to find interfaces where you click on the player that you want to remove to select it, and then click the `remove` button to actually do so. You can know which player was selected with this code:

Player selected = playersListView.getSelectedValue();

If there is a selection (`selected != null`) you could either call `removePlayerByName(selected.getName())`, or even better, code a `removePlayer(Player p)` that did not rely on names, but on a (currently missing) implementation of `Player.equals(Player another)`.

Comment: This seems like an interesting solution. It's a bit too advanced for me, though. I will definitely do some research and see if I can wrap my head around this.